# Update many records at same time in Node js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to update many records with different attribute values. I use Nodejs, Sequelize and Postgresql.
Ex: 
I have 2 product records:
ID, name, quantity
1, tv, 10
2, radio, 12
Now, i want to update product id = 1 set quantity = 20 and product id = 2 set quantity = 30 at same time.
Thanks you for seen my post.

Comment: try to use async parallel for update

Comment: if use async parallel, how to know that record update success or fail ?

Comment: if there is any error , at that moment it will be terminated.You can also add console.log() for tracing the success or failure.

Comment: ok. Thanks you very much ^^